# 4.18 Lab Zybooks (Output range with increment of 5)

Tags: c++

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plOtL.png)

[New line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuvix.png)

Hello everyone, I am fairly new to coding and am currently doing Zybooks for school. This may seem like such a simple error, but I have been having trouble finding where to insert the new line. Everywhere I insert it gives me an error or extends my line rather than condensing it into one. Thank y'all for the help!

The code below is in C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  int x,y;
    
    cin >> x >> y;
   
    if(y>=x){
        
        for(int i=x;i<=y;i=i+5){
            
            cout << i << " " << endl;
          
        }
    }else{
        
        cout<< "Second integer can't be less than the first."<< endl;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to insert a new line but every time I start a new line, it starts a new line for the whole output. I'm trying to get my output as the "expected output" in the photo.

Comment: `cout << i << ' ';` inside the loop. `cout << endl;` outside the loop.

Comment: Hey, @RohanBari  thank you for the quick reply! I tried to insert the new line outside the loop but still received the same error code as the one before. Any other suggestions? Thank you!